# iPhone example to go through

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Can you provide me a basic iPhone example which has the following;

a. It is primarily a navigation-based app (Top-level view, Detail view, etc)

b. It also uses table (to present list of items, item details, add, edit, delete)

c. It uses Core Data for storing the list items

d. Optionally, it would be really great if it uses an API for retrieving some of the table data (otherwise user entered if API does not return).

While I do have individual examples for all these thing, I ma basically looking for an example which kind of combines all these things into a single app.

I have already gone through some of the IOS developer reference and hence would want other combined examples.

Any reference examples would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked through the [iOS Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Types) library? You'll find examples of all these. They have [TopSongs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopSongs/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008925-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) (API, Navigation Views, Table Views, Core Data) and CoreDataBooks for Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a project using the Navigation based template and select "Use Core Data" you will get the skeleton of exactly the type of app you want.

Comment: yes, but i want a comination like "Core Data" + Nav + Table + API use

Comment: The example project does that.

Answer (score 0):

Examples covering all of those are on Apple's developer website, [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/ios).

Answer (score -1):

I used this one is one, to learn this: http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/#create-db